# Cannot get image EJS using express.static (Node JS)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

i try to collect image from uploads path using ejs, this is my file route

[image: path]

this is my code on 'dotemplate.js'

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2 style="text-align: center; font-size: 12pt" >ATTACHMENT</h2>
    <hr size="10px">
    <div>

        <img src="/picture-1592300001150.jpg" alt="Attachment photo" />
    </div>
            <div>
```

this is on 'controller.js' on path "ticket"

```
 ExportPDFdeorder: async function(req, res, next){
    const dord = await lstTicketById(req.params.id);
    try {
        const name = await Date.now();
        ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, './template', "deorder.template.ejs"),{Ticket: dord,}, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500).json({status: "error", data: err});
            } else {
                let options = {
                    "format": "A4",
                    "orientation": "portrait",
                    "border": {
                        "top": "1cm",            // default is 0, units: mm, cm, in, px
                        "right": "2cm",
                        "bottom": "1cm",
                        "left": "1cm"
                    },
                };
                pdf.create(data, options).toFile(`temp/${name}.pdf`, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.send(err);
                    } else {
                        var file= `temp/${name}.pdf`;
                        fs.readFile(file,function(err,data){
                            res.contentType("application/pdf");
                            res.send(data);


                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        return res.status(500).json({status: "error", data: "internal server error"});
    }
}
```

};

this is my code on 'server.js'

```
app.use('./ticket', express.static('uploads'))
```

app.listen(config.port, () => console.log(`server started`));

i still cannot get image from upload path, can someone help to tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i already solved this things, i use `<img src="http:/localhost:3000/users1592300001150.jpg" alt="Attachment photo" />`

Answer (score 2):

To get an image in a static folder:

1) Configure the app:

```
app.use('/ticket', express.static('uploads'));
```

2) In your view, access something in the `uploads` folder like so:

```
<img src="/ticket/picture-1592300001150.jpg" alt="Attachment photo" />
```

Comment: i already try this, also i route app.use('/ticket/template', express.static('uploads')); still did not help. but i find solution take image using full url like localhost:3000/picture-1592300001150.jpg. and this problem already solved, thanks for your repply!

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for static files from folder to folder, but you should do by accessing from your localhost url

here in `template.ejs`

```
<img src="./pictures/image.png">
```

that is incorrect path, you should access in localhost. replace that with

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/pictures/image.png">
```

but is not good to write localhost url at views, so just parse it in route

at the `route.js` just parse static url in variable

```
...
const staticUrl = `http://127.0.0.1:${port}`;
...

router.get('/auth/register', (req, res) => {
    const context = {
        layout: 'layouts/auth',
        useStatic: staticUrl,
        ...
    }
    res.render('auth/register', context);
});
```

then in `template.ejs`

```
<img src="<%= useStatic %>/pictures/pdsl-images-3.png">
```